# Java responses to browser

Tags: java, io, serversocket

This code should be able to respond to client browser.

This is my code for listening to browser:

```
public class simpleServer extends Thread {
static ServerSocket serverSocket;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
    Thread t = new simpleServer();
    t.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try (Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());) {
            String received = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println("What received: " + received);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Running code result:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
at myp.simpleServer.run(simpleServer.java:23)
```

I try `localhost:8000`

But the unable to connect!

[image]

Comment: Your code has to be hosted on a web server before you'll be able to connect to it using HTTP.

Comment: @IAmTheSquidward this code is supposed to emulate the web server.

Comment: OP: you may start reading all the request as `String`s and printing it out in the Java console. Probably you will get this result in your browser since there's no response from the server but you should see a message printed in console that executes the Java application. Your current problem is that you probably aren't receiving `"http://localhost:8000"` as first message from client, and also you're comparing `String`s with `==` when you should use `equals` method.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i corrected String comparing.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza oh, I gotcha. My bad.

Comment: @user3808021 you should add an `else` statement as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code and works as expected:

```
public class SimpleServer implements Runnable {
    static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
        Thread t = new Thread(new SimpleServer());
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try (Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                //this is too much noise
                //you can directly wrap the result from socket.getInputStream()
                //into the BufferedReader
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(in) )) {

                System.out.println("request from browser client:");
                String line;
                //reads and prints every line from the request
                while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you just need to write an appropriate response for your client.

More info:

- [A Simple Http Server with Java/Socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10788125/1065197)
- [simple HTTP server in Java using only Java SE API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3732109/1065197)

Comment: `GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you fire a URL from browser it by default calls get method with a header something like this

```
Got connection
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

So your condition    if (in.readUTF() == "http://yourhost:8000") will never be satisfied.Going forward with your error.The server as per your code the server will always be in reading mode because of this statement    if (in.readUTF() == "http://yourhost:8000") so it will not send any response to you browser.To help you to understand the how it works I have modified your code as follows:

```
@Override
public void run() {

        try (Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());) {
            System.out.println("Got connection");
            String line="";
            while(null!=(line=in.readLine())){
            System.out.println(line);
            }
           // if (in.readUTF() == "http://yourhostname:8000") {
             //   System.out.println("Browser want local host");
           // }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: REsult is : `GET / HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:8000 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Connection: keep-alive`

Comment: But, cant respond to browser request, why?

Comment: As server is always reading data from browser and is waiting for data from browser.I think you need to write a separate thread that will read data from the socket.