# Java - Client-server program - http response

Tags: java, http, client-server

I'm new to coding and Java,I have create a simple client-server program where the client can request a file. Its content will be displayed in the browser page together with some details like the data type and the length.
I'm now having a problem, I'm not sure how to display in the browser the server response for a correct connection like "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" and for the connection closed like "Connection: close".
I have a method to handle the response as follow:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ReadRequest {

    private final static int LISTENING_PORT = 50505;
    protected static Socket client;
    protected static PrintStream out;
    static String requestedFile;


    
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(LISTENING_PORT);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to create listening socket.");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Listening on port " + LISTENING_PORT);

        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket connection = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("\nConnection from "+ connection.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                ConnectionThread thread = new ConnectionThread(connection);
                thread.start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Server socket shut down unexpectedly!");
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            System.out.println("Exiting.");
        }
    }
    

    private static void handleConnection(Socket connection) {

        String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
        String httpRootDir = "C:\\Users\\"+(username)+"\\Downloads\\";
        client = connection;
        try {
            
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintStream (client.getOutputStream());

            String line = null;     
            String req = null;      

            
            req = in.readLine();
            
            line = req;
            while (line.length() > 0)
            {
                line = in.readLine();
            }
            
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(req);

            if (!st.nextToken().equals("GET"))
            {                                      
            
                sendErrorResponse(501);                                       
                return;
            }

            
            requestedFile = st.nextToken();

            File f = new File(httpRootDir + requestedFile);

    
            if (!f.canRead())
            {
                
                sendErrorResponse(404);                                       
                return;
            }
            
            sendResponseHeader(getMimeType(requestedFile),(int) f.length());
            
            sendFile(f,client.getOutputStream());

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while communicating with client: " + e);
        }
        finally {  
            try {
                connection.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
            System.out.println("Connection closed.");
        };
    }
    

    private static void sendResponseHeader(String type,int length)
    {
           
          out.println("Content-type: " +type+"\r\n");
          out.println("Content-Length: " +length+"\r\n");
 
    }
    
    
    private static void sendErrorResponse(int errorCode)
    {
        switch(errorCode) {
        case 404:
            out.print("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");    
            out.println("Connection: close " ); 
            out.println("Content-type: text/plain" +"\r\n");              
            out.println("<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body> <h2>Error: 404 Not Found</h2> <p>The resource that you requested does not exist on this server.</p> </body></html>");
            break;
        case 501:
            out.print("HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented");    
            out.println("Connection: close " ); 
            out.println("Content-type: text/plain" +"\r\n");                                     
            break;
        }                               
    }


    private static String getMimeType(String fileName) {
        int pos = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (pos < 0)  
            return "g-application/x-unknown";
        String ext = fileName.substring(pos+1).toLowerCase();
        if (ext.equals("txt")) return "text/plain";
        else if (ext.equals("html")) return "text/html";
        else if (ext.equals("htm")) return "text/html";
        else if (ext.equals("css")) return "text/css";
        else if (ext.equals("js")) return "text/javascript";
        else if (ext.equals("java")) return "text/x-java";
        else if (ext.equals("jpeg")) return "image/jpeg";
        else if (ext.equals("jpg")) return "image/jpeg";
        else if (ext.equals("png")) return "image/png";
        else if (ext.equals("gif")) return "image/gif";
        else if (ext.equals("ico")) return "image/x-icon";
        else if (ext.equals("class")) return "application/java-vm";
        else if (ext.equals("jar")) return "application/java-archive";
        else if (ext.equals("zip")) return "application/zip";
        else if (ext.equals("xml")) return "application/xml";
        else if (ext.equals("xhtml")) return"application/xhtml+xml";
        else return "g-application/x-unknown";
        
    }

    
    private static void sendFile(File file, OutputStream socketOut) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream infile = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
            OutputStream outfile = new BufferedOutputStream(socketOut);
            while (true) {
                int x = infile.read(); 
                if (x < 0)
                    break; 
                outfile.write(x);  
            }
            outfile.flush();
        }
    }
    
    private static class ConnectionThread extends Thread {
        Socket connection;
        ConnectionThread(Socket connection) {
            this.connection = connection;
        }
        public void run() {
            handleConnection(connection);
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion on how I can do that? thank you

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code? It  is not very obvious what you are doing and what you are trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: Updated with the rest of the code

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788125/a-simple-http-server-with-java-socket

Comment: Thank you, I can print my text like suggested in the link, my point is, to get the status code of the connection (http), like 200, there shouldn't be a method that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You make your way too complicate if you try to reinvent the wheel implementing Request/Response communication. It is better just to use the Spring MVC.